# Angular best way to get conditional element to automatically scroll into view

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an element that that is conditionally inserted with an `*ngIf` condition.  When it is inserted I want to scroll it into view.   The following technique works but it seems clumsy and I would like to improve it.

```html
          <app-text-create id="textcreate" *ngIf="modeNewEntry"          
                  (load)="document.getElementById('textcreate').scrollIntoView()"
          ></app-text-create>
```

When the component state property `modeNewEntry` goes `true` the text entry box gets inserted on the bottom of the page.  Without the `scrollIntoView()` call it is generally not visible.

Is there a better way to get access to the `HTMLElement` than the `document.getElementById(..)` expression?

PS.  The IDE I am using, WebStorm, thinks the `document` reference as undefined even though this does works.  Is that a bug or is there a reason for that?

Comment: Do you had try using reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the component in a wrapping `div`:

```
<div #textCreate>
  <app-text-create id="textcreate" *ngIf="modeNewEntry">
  </app-text-create>
</div>
```

And then when you click a button to set `modeNewEntry` to true, also call `scrollIntoView()` on the `ElementRef`'s `nativeElement` for this `div`:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  modeNewEntry = false;
  @ViewChild('textCreate', { static: false }) textCreateComponent: ElementRef;

  showComponent() {
    this.modeNewEntry = true;
    this.textCreateComponent.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Code Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-in-view-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)  for your ref.

Comment: I thought about using the ViewChild decorator but I forgot that about the nativeElement property that it is contained.  Also I don't need the id attribute anymore.